Trouble Accessing SharePoint Records via Graph API – 'Access Denied' Error
Our 'Target Application' that is XXX, and that is multitenant, and we are using the YYY app ID and secret to generate a token using the client credentials flow in Postman. The SharePoint sites are in the YYY tenant. We are able to fetch records from all sites, but when we try to access this Graph API endpoint: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Users/%7BuserId%7D/drive/root/children, we receive an "Access denied" error.
For the Target Application XXX, we have granted all necessary Graph permissions.
Here is the XXX application permission SS:

For the demo application that is YYY, we have added the Sites.Selected permission for application level.
NOTE: We have used the token from the YYY application.

The error "403 Access Denied" usually occurs if the access token does not have required permissions to perform the action.
Initially I created demo application YYY and granted Sites.Selected permission for application level and generated access token using YYY application.
And when I call the https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID/drive/root/children API got the same error:

To fetch the user's OneDrive, the application must be granted with Files.Read.All application type permission for YYY:

Generated access token by using YYY application:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:AppID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

Make sure the access token contains Files.Read.All role:

Now I am able to get user's OneDrive successfully:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID/drive/root/children


